# Print/Debug.log does not show output in Unity console

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity. The print doesn't work when I press. 
I have attached the script to the character.
What am I doing wrong?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator Anim;

    void Start()
    {
        Anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("1"))
        {
            print("I pressed 1");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Been a while since I've used Unity but don't you need to specify the key code?  So your code would be `if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))`?  Taken from here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html

Comment: @Mkalafut not worked unfortinately.

Comment: Works for me. Questions asking for help with a bug must include a [mre]. Voting to close until one is included in the body of the question.

Comment: My problem fixed in the below answer's comment. I couldn't understand, why downvote ?

Comment: @mrbengi It's unhelpful to future visitors because it doesn't describe a problem in a helpful way. The question does not even explain which key you are pressing. It works for me when I press the 1 key in the [number row.](https://www.typing-lessons.org/images/keyboards/lesson_18.png)

Comment: @Ruzihm Sorry I'm new to Unity, as I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Debug.Log("I pressed 1") instead

or

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) { Debug.Log("Space key was pressed."); }
```

Comment: Its not work, too

Comment: if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("Space key was pressed.");
        } is this working with Space?

Comment: Or try KeyCode.Keypad1

Comment: Space key worked, thanks.